# Artifactory service start failing with tomcat startup in linux

Tags: tomcat, artifactory

I have installed artifactory and trying to install it as a service. I have managed to execute the installService.sh script under ARTIFACTORY_HOME/bin folder with root. I had no issues while installing. However post the service installation i am seeing below error while trying to issue sudo systemctl start artifactory.service.

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start artifactory.service
Job for artifactory.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status artifactory.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl  status artifactory.service
● artifactory.service - Setup Systemd script for Artifactory in Tomcat Servlet Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-10-07 15:07:29 IST; 3s ago
  Process: 3448 ExecStart=/home/ciadmin/devops/utils/artifactory-oss-5.5.1/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 07 15:07:29 localhost.localdomain artifactoryManage.sh[3448]: sh: /home/ciadmin/devops/utils/artifactory-oss-5.5.1/tomcat/bin/startup.sh: Permission denied
Oct 07 15:07:29 localhost.localdomain artifactoryManage.sh[3448]: ** ERROR: Artifactory Tomcat server did not start. Please check the logs
Oct 07 15:07:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 07 15:07:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Setup Systemd script for Artifactory in Tomcat Servlet Engine.
Oct 07 15:07:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 07 15:07:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Is this and deceiving error for tomcat setup? I have no clue. All the folders are with right permissions and the tomcat scripts are set to executable permissions as well.

**Process: 7831 ExecStart=/home/ciadmin/devops/utils/artifactory-oss-5.5.1/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)**

The script tomcat startup.sh is executable as well

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -l /home/ciadmin/devops/utils/artifactory-oss-5.5.1/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 artifactory artifactory 1904 Jan 19  2017 /home/ciadmin/devops/utils/artifactory-oss-5.5.1/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

I have modified the /etc/secutiry/limit.conf with artifactory limits.
artifactory      soft    nproc           65535
artifactory      hard    nproc           65535
artifactory      soft    nofile          65535
artifactory      hard    nofile          65535

Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Any additional details in the `catalina.out` or the tomcat localhost log files?

Comment: what is the contents of the artifactory.service file?

Comment: As Yinon mentioned, check the catalina.log